# SQL facing error while running bcp

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am facing error wile running this  in sql server 2000

```
 bcp  "select dmedocno ,dmename,dmeauthor,dmekeywords from document
 where repositoryid=4 and dmedocno between 1 and 60000 order by
 dmedocno" queryout c:\LR_Query29_cutover_19_August.csv -Swsapp0772  -T -c -t","
```

Error is:

> Server: Msg 103, Level 15, State 7, Line 1
>   The identifier that starts with 'select dmedocno ,dmename,dmeauthor,dmekeywords from document where repositoryid=4 and dmedocno between 1 and 60000 order by dmed' is too long. 
> Maximum length is 128.
>   Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.

Answer (score 0):

why your sql server treats the query as identifier? hm...
Check default QUOTED_IDENTIFIER option for the server, try to set it to OFF